# Tracking 'Useful Links'

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I'm building a Useful Links database for a Classic ASP site. The table has the usual ID, Title, URL, Description, DateAdded and DateModified. I also want to record in the table each time a link has been clicked or viewed.

I wondered if anyone had built such a system or knows of a way that I could accomplish this?

Thank you.

Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a redirector page that records the click then redirects the user on to website. eg: /LaunchSite.asp?Site=www.site.com

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)! With no need for database...